# Starting with Klein geometry

Tags: geometry

I have read that in Klein's approach, geometry can be seen as the study of invariants under a group of transformations. We begin with a space $X$ and a subgroup $G$ of all its bijections (tough usually it would be shrink to a subgroup of the homeomorphisms or diffeomorphisms of $X$). This is called the principal group. Next step is to fix a subspace $S \subseteq X$ and look at
$$
H:=Stab_G (S) \subseteq G,
$$
the subgroup of $G$ that leaves invariant the configuration $S$. Klein's idea was that the space
$$
G/H
$$
is interesting, and this kind of spaces are called homogeneous spaces or Klein geometries. In particular, if the action is transitive and we have $S=\{x\}$ for $x\in X$,
$$
X\approx G/H
$$
that is, we recover the set of points. But  I have been told that we also recover the *geometric properties*. **How that can be done from here?**

I'd like to see it with an example. If I consider $X$ as the Euclidean space, an arbitrary point $P\in X$ and the rigid motions $E(3)$ as the principal group $G$, then $H=O(3)$ and it is clear to me that $X=G/H=\mathbb{R}^3$. But **how can we deduce from here the gist of this geometry, that is, the Euclidean distance formula or the scalar product?** Is there any **general method** that can be used with any Klein geometry to deduce its "metric" or something?

Comment: Is this article on the [Cayley–Klein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Klein_metric) useful?

Comment: Not really, sorry.

Comment: I recently answered a similar question on Cayley-Klein geometries here; https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3942087/1257.  It may not be at the level of abstraction or generality you're looking for, but it gives a good reference that works through how geometric properties such as distance and angle are recovered.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the key is in the adjoint representation of $H$ over $\mathfrak{g}$. Because in this context we can look for invariant subspaces and I guess that "inside" is hidden the information for the geometry. I have seen a good explanation in *Parabolic Geometries*, by Andreas Cap and  Jan Slovak, page 6, but I don't fully understand yet.

I have also found useful the foreword of *Differential geometry, Cartan's generalization of Klein Erlangen program*, by Sharpe and Chern; although I cannot see yet how the Maurer-Cartan form let us recover the metric.

**Edited**
After a stop I have returned to the topic, and I have found that the whole chapter 1 of *Parabolic Geometries* is devoted to this issue, specifically section 1.4. When I finish reading I will edit again to write a summary, or an outline.

On the other hand, I think that the book of Sharpe is the typical book it is worth reading once you know about the topic, because you can think a lot of important stuff, but you need to have a minimum of ideas in your mind to be able to follow it.